# Regarding positions of elements within a row's 'islands of positive values'

Tags: arrays, numpy

Consider a **specified row** in a numpy integer array.   My task has 3 parts:

1. Identify the locations of any positive islands (ie: consec positive values) in the specified row.
2. Identify the lengths of each of these positive islands.
3. Determine  (True or False) if the island element that is closest in value to the row index is in the FIRST or LAST island position.

The following code, I believe, answers parts a) and b).

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[-1, -4, -2, -8,  8, -3, -5, -6,  7],
                [-4, -9, -1,  3,  8, -7, -6,  2, -5],
                [ 4,  6,  9,  3, -1, -2,  5,  4,  8],
                [ 5, -1,  2,  5,  6,  7, -3, -4,  1]])

row_idx = 2
arr_row = arr[row_idx]

mask = arr_row > 0                    
changes = np.concatenate(([mask[0]], mask[:-1] != mask[1:], [mask[-1]]))

isl_idx = np.where(changes)[0]      # 1st index of islands
pos_idx = isl_idx[::2]              # 1st index of POSITIVE islands
print('pos_idx = ', pos_idx)

pos_len = np.diff(isl_idx)[::2]     # length of POSITIVE islands
print('pos_len = ', pos_len)
print()
```

When **row_idx = 2**, for example, we have output:

```
pos_idx = [0, 6]    # first indices of the two positive islands
pos_len = [4,3])    # lengths of the two positive islands
```

My problem is that I can't find a good way to tackle part c).   The desired output, for the example above, would look like:

```
firstLast = [True, False]
```

Explanation:  We are in **row_idx = 2**,   so:
The value in the 1st positive island closest to 2 is 3, and this 3 is indeed in the FIRST or LAST position of its island. (**True**) 
The value in the 2nd positive island closest to 2 is 4, which is not in the FIRST or LAST position of its island. (**False**)

Comment: Unrealated, but I think it's a bit strange that you would be looking into the data to find closest value to the **row index**. Interesting problem still.

Comment: hi Quang - involving the row index does indeed seem strange, but it is correct.  Here's a rough analogy: Imagine towns 1,2,3... along a train track.    A train leaves town 2 and visits towns 4,6,9,3 in that order before returning to town 2.   We want to visit town 3 either first or last because it is close to 2.   An order like 4,6,3,9  would necessarily involve extra travel.